# How to Rotate an Object Based On Swipe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a script to move an object back anf forth based on swipe similarly to a game called Sky Rusher on the iOS App Store. The movement in the original game lets you swipe in any direction and an object moves in the same direction. However, the object also "bounces" for lack of a better term. For example, if you swipe to the left, the object will tilt to the left and then tilt back to its original position. For the best example I can give, please take a look at this video for a demonstartion of the game:

[Sky Rusher Gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69pe6OB9aIk)

This is the code I currently have (the object also doesn't move back and forth when swiping, not sure what==y that is but have an idea on how to fix it):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 currentPos;
private Vector3 touchPos;
private float screenWidth;
private float screenHeight;
private float touchX;
private float touchY;
private float objectX;
private float objectY;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    touchX = 0;
    touchY = 0;
    screenWidth = (float)Screen.width / 2.0f;
    screenHeight = (float)Screen.height / 2.0f;
    currentPos = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

            //touchPos = new Vector3((touch.position.x - screenWidth)/screenWidth, (touch.position.y - screenHeight)/screenHeight + 1, 0.0f);
            touchPos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0.0f);

            touchX = (touchPos.x - screenWidth)/screenHeight - 1f;
            touchY = (touchPos.y - screenHeight)/screenHeight + 1f;

            //objectX = ((currentPos.x * screenWidth) - screenWidth)/screenWidth;
            //objectY = ((currentPos.y * screenHeight) - screenHeight)/screenHeight;
            objectX = currentPos.x;
            objectY = currentPos.y;

            objectX += (touchX - objectX) * 1.5f;
            //objectY += (touchY - objectY) * 1.5f;

            if(touchX >= 0.9f)
            {
                objectX+=0.05f;
            }
            else if(touchX <= -0.9f)
            {
                objectX-=0.05f;
            }

            currentPos = new Vector3(objectX, objectY, 0.0f);
            transform.position = currentPos;
        }
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    /*
    // Compute a fontSize based on the size of the screen width.
    GUI.skin.label.fontSize = (int)(Screen.width / 40.0f);

    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 20, screenWidth, screenHeight * 0.25f),
        "Pos: x = " + (objectX.ToString("f2")) +
        ", y = " + objectY.ToString("f2"));

    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 50, screenWidth, screenHeight * 0.25f),
    "Touch: x = " + (touchX.ToString("f2")) +
    ", y = " + (touchY.ToString("f2")));
    */
}
}
```

I need my object to tilt when moved similarly to how it is done in sky rusher. My game is played in a landscape orientation on an iOS Device using Unity Remote 5 and Unity 2018.3.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to achieve this effect, if I understood correctly what you mean:

1) Each time `touchX >= .9f` (you are moving right) apply `localRotation` along Z axis with some angle.
2) Each time `touchX <= -.9f` (you are moving left) apply `localRotation` along Z axis with some negative angle.

To make this look smooth and not jumpy, apply rotation along several frames, first calculating target rotation, then using `RotateTowards` with some given speed. Here is yourr code slightly modified:

```
public float tiltEffectAngle = 20;
public float tiltEffectSpeed = 90f;

void Update() {
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

            //touchPos = new Vector3((touch.position.x - screenWidth)/screenWidth, (touch.position.y - screenHeight)/screenHeight + 1, 0.0f);
            touchPos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0.0f);

            touchX = (touchPos.x - screenWidth) / screenHeight - 1f;
            touchY = (touchPos.y - screenHeight) / screenHeight + 1f;

            //objectX = ((currentPos.x * screenWidth) - screenWidth)/screenWidth;
            //objectY = ((currentPos.y * screenHeight) - screenHeight)/screenHeight;
            objectX = currentPos.x;
            objectY = currentPos.y;

            objectX += (touchX - objectX) * 1.5f;
            //objectY += (touchY - objectY) * 1.5f;



            if (touchX >= 0.9f) {
                objectX += 0.05f;
                targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(
                    transform.localEulerAngles.x,
                    transform.localEulerAngles.y,
                    tiltEffectAngle);
            } else if (touchX <= -0.9f) {
                objectX -= 0.05f;
                targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(
                    transform.localEulerAngles.x,
                    transform.localEulerAngles.y,
                    -tiltEffectAngle);
            }

            currentPos = new Vector3(objectX, objectY, 0.0f);
            transform.position = currentPos;
        }
    }
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, tiltEffectSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I tested this on the touchscreen, the tilting works eprfectly, however, when I run it on a mobile device with a 9:16 aspect ratio the object can only move to the left edge of the screen and cannot move all the way tp the right edge, only back to the center. Even if the object starts out on the right edge of the screen when cviewed form the camera, I can move all the way to the left edge but not all the way back to the right edge. Do you have any ideas or potential solutions for this? I tried changing the sensitivity for just the right side but it didnt work either.

Comment: Maybe because of this typo in your code: should be probably `touchX = (touchPos.x - screenWidth) / screenWidth - 1f;` and not `touchX = (touchPos.x - screenWidth) / screenHeight - 1f;`

Comment: I made that change to the code, but I still get the same result. The cube never moves more to the right than the center, even if I change the position and sensitivity in the editor.

Comment: The touch position is in Screen Coordinate, but the object position is not

Comment: Found the issue. The -1f should not be there, it is what prevents the object form going all the way to the right.